# Objective C: AES 256 Encryption with NSData Key

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Previously I did Triple DES encryption to encrypt some data using a string key file, by defining a method

```
+ (NSData *)tripleDESEncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key dataToEncrypt:(NSData*)convertedData   {}.
```

Now, similarly I am doing AES 256 encryption. But this time, I can not use a string as the key. I need to get NSData from a file in resources using

```
NSData *keyData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:keyPath];
```

As I need to pass this key as parameter, I tried to convert it into string with

```
NSString *key = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:keyData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

but it returned NULL. So, How to use the Data key for AES 256 encryption ?

EDIT: I got that I should not use UTF8 encoding as the data file was made by Base64 encoding of a string. So Now the question is, how to get the string key using Base64 from keyData ?

Comment: Did you already use breakpoint tool to ensure that `keyData` variable is not `NULL`? check your `keyPath`

Comment: Keypath is fine. Keydata also exists: <792f83e5 806c5f51 abf8fdba 9b371610 b8f2c474 b24d89d2 707c7da0 815b964a>. I checked it long back using breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

If `key` variable returned `NULL`. Try to use like this.

```
NSString* key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[keyData bytes]];
```

Refer to [KennyTM's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467844/convert-utf-8-encoded-nsdata-to-nsstring)

**UPDATE 1:** You can also read the string directly from your file without convert in `NSData`

By NSFileHandle:

```
NSString * path = @"your key file path";
NSFileHandle * fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:path];
NSData * buffer = nil;
while ((buffer = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:1024])) {
    //do something with buffer
}
```

or use NSString

```
NSString * key = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Refer to [Dave DeLong's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4208652/696088)

**Note:** Ensure your `keyPath` variable , Is it correct in the format of full or relative path?

**UPDATE 2:** You can also deal with Base64 Encoding with [Matt Gallagher NSData+Base64 Class&Header](http://projectswithlove.com/projects/NSData_Base64.zip) (See also his blog [there](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html))

For encode base64

```
NSString * key = [[path dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64EncodedString];
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Tried that. Still it is null !

Comment: Actually, you need to read the key string from your file in resource asset,right? just read the string from your file directly . see my update answer

Comment: EDIT: I got that I should not use UTF8 encoding as the data file was made by Base64 encoding of a string. So Now the question is, how to get the string key using Base64 from keyData ?

Comment: I guess, I can use this line of your answer: NSString * key = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; , but I only need to use Base64 instead of NSUTF8StringEncoding. How ?

Answer (score 0):

Read the file:

```
NSData* myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:myFileWithPath];
```

Then use one of the implementations in this post:

[Base64 encoding options on the Mac and iPhone](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/base64-encoding-options-on-mac-and.html)

to do your Base64 conversion.

Note:  simply sticking your decryption key into a file is a bad idea.  Optimally, the key would be stored securely by being encrypted by the user's own key.