# Objective-C using print "\r$i"

Tags: objective-c, perl, printf, nstask

I can use `NSTask` to grab the output of `stdout`, create a string and put it into an `NSTextField` without issue, although how would I make the output behave like `print "\r$i"`?

This perl script demonstrates the output:

```
$|++;

for ($i=0; $i<1000000; $i++) {
    print "\r$i";
}
print "\n";
```

Is it possible to take stdout from an NSTask and output in Objective-C like this?

Comment: You could use `scanf()` in a loop.  `scanf("%d", &i);`.  The form of the input would have to be very predictable.

Comment: @ryyker, I would be worried about a buffer overflow with `scanf()` possibly. Does `fgets` exist in objective-c?

Comment: It appears to be: ***[see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4208552/645128)***.

Comment: Provide an example of a few lines of the input you are getting.  fgets in a loop is sometimes used to read from stdin

Comment: @ryyker, Interesting, thanks for that. An example would be any console app that overwrites it's output on the same line. So if you had "Hello", the next line would overwrite it with "World" (using \r instead of \n). Still not clear on how to take the stdout and loop it though as you mentioned to an `NSTextField` so any new output "overwrites" the same line.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the real question.  Let me try again:  I think what you are asking is How do you 1) clear the terminal, 2) place the cursor position to the top left corner of the terminal, and 3) start writing your next line.  In short, controlling the position of the terminal cursor.  If this is correct, then have you looked at ***[ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)***?  (not the easy answer, but most often referenced for cursor control questions by others)

Comment: @ryyker, Yes precisely. I realize it's not "overwriting" the line but more a matter of manipulating the cursor in a tty session. So the question is can that behavior be called upon in a Cocoa View? I installed ncurses, although I'm needing to have a native solution - as not everyone would be willing or capable to compile and install it.