# reading and separating file using byte comparison

Tags: objective-c

I have to read a file which in .dat format and separate data based on 2 first consecutive zero byte comes. first half is json data and other half is binary data.

How should I go about it?

I tried using NSData dataWithContentsOfFile method and read it and then convert it in byte array and compare bytes. Somehow, its not working.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code that’s not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same kind of procedure that you would use to read a file by lines. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044334/objective-c-reading-a-file-line-by-line) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707427/how-to-read-data-from-nsfilehandle-line-by-line) are earlier answers on SO regarding reading a file line-by-line. Just change `\n` to the byte sequence that is applicable.