# iOS Memory Leak on NSFilehandle line-by-line File Reader

Tags: ios, ios4

I'm using the following method of reading a text file one line at a time (1.1 million total lines) and the memory footprint of my app on the simulator grows to the total filesize of the text file (480MB).  Do I need to implement an autorelease pool drain to manage the memory consumption?

[How to read data from NSFileHandle line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707427/how-to-read-data-from-nsfilehandle-line-by-line/3711079#3711079)

```
NSString *docDir = [AppSession documentsDirectory];
NSString *csvpath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/docs/output.csv"];

__block NSUInteger count = 0;

DDFileReader * reader = [[DDFileReader alloc] initWithFilePath:csvpath];
[reader enumerateLinesUsingBlock:^(NSString * line, BOOL * stop) 
{
    count++;      
}];

NSLog(@"FINAL COUNT %i", count);
[reader release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It would have to be in your DDFileReader class, inside the loop in `enumerateLinesUsingBlock:`. You cannot correctly do it from the bit of code you have posted here.

Comment: I added an autorelease pool drain in the while statement and that didn't help.      while (stop == NO && (line = [self readLine])) {
        NSAutoreleasePool * readPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        block(line, &stop);
        [readPool drain];
    }