# ios reading a binary file is slow

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I am developing a application that needs to read/write some data. So my first solution was to store the data in a json encoded string in a sqlite database. Since deserialization of the json string was slow (about 5sec) and i couldn't pre buffer any data i decided to store the data in a binary file (on the disk). For that i have implemented a reader that reads the binary file. Now i have compared the speed results and found out that the times are more or less the same (the file size is better though).

I am using NSFileHandle for reading the file and i am reading it line by line. I tested this on a iPhone 3GS with 0.5 MB of data. Is this normal?   Should i switch to reading the file using C/C++ functions? Would it be any better? Does any one have any experience with this? My code is more or less based on this question [How to read data from NSFileHandle line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707427/how-to-read-data-from-nsfilehandle-line-by-line).

Thanks!