# How to read a file line by line in objective-c in the least number of lines in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, file, handle

What is the easiest and most terse way to read a file line-by-line in Objective-C?

If you think using the methods from C/C++ are better, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have small files you can do the following:

```
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
for (NSString *line in [fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]) {
    // Do something
}
```

otherwise, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707427/how-to-read-data-from-nsfilehandle-line-by-line) question for a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in two lines:

```
NSString *s = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"foo.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSArray lines = [s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```