# Trying to use Dave DeLong DDFileReader Class

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I'm trying to use Dave DeLongs [DDFileReader Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707427/how-to-read-data-from-nsfilehandle-line-by-line#3711079) but I'm getting an error while building.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DDFileReader", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in tmnAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The "DDFileReader.m" has a set target membership and is under build phases in the "compile sources"

I'm on 10.8.3 with XCode 4.6.2
I'm sure this is a noob error but I still would appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: does this app compile for the device? also, do you have "`@implementation DDFileReader`" in your .m file?

Comment: In which .m file should the `@implementation DDFileReader`be? In the DDFileReader.m or in the AppDelegate.m? Sorry total noob in Objective-C. I just pushed it to my github account https://github.com/fabiantheblind/Shorcuts/tree/master/Shortcuts If you want to take a look…

Comment: It should be in the DDFileReader.m file.  Right now that file is essentially empty.

Comment: Had a typo in the repo name https://github.com/fabiantheblind/Shortcuts

Comment: Typos in repo names are not (usually) a big deal. I was able to download and diagnose easily. Thanks for making the code available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I look in your DDFileReader.m file that you've checked into GitHub, the entire contents is:

```
//DDFileReader.m

#import "DDFileReader.h"

@interface NSData (DDAdditions)

@end
```

You need to have the entire code snippet from the .m file copied in there.

Comment: Oh. Sorry I wrote "DDFileReader.h" it is the .m file that I ment

Comment: Nawwww, this was an easy mistake to make and not an idiot one.  Sometimes it just takes two pairs of eyes to see it.

Comment: +1 for making me feel not that stupid :) BTW after removing all those ARC errors - it works now. Thanks a lot