# How to make an array of numbers? (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsnumber

I was trying to make an array of numbers. I need to call every element of this array. (array[i] ). I have done it like this:

```
NSNumber *array[] = {@0.240128f , @0.240128f , @0.953934f , @1.181351f, @1.382523f, @1.497086f, @1.437790f , @0.851196f};
```

but when I am calling this array it gives me an error:

> Expected method to read array element not found on object of type "NSNumber"

Additional code moved from a comment:

```
int SIZE = 97;
fftw_complex *data, *fft_result, *ifft_result;
fftw_plan     plan_forward, plan_backward;
int           i;
NSArray * array = @[@0.240128f , @0.240128f , @0.953934f , @1.181351f, @1.382523f, @1.497086f, @1.437790f , @0.851196f];

float a0 = [array[0] floatValue];
data = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * SIZE);
fft_result  = ...
ifft_result = ...
plan_forward  = ...
plan_backward ...

for( i = 0 ; i < SIZE ; i++ ) {
    data[i][0] = array[i];
    data[i][1] = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: `data[i][0] = array[i];` should be `[array[i] floatValue];`

Comment: @Zaph
YOU SOLVE IT ,
its working, i was hanging here from two days ago :)
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems

First the statement for creating the array has to errors, the "[]" after the variable and using "{}" instead of "[]" to initialize an array.

Then from a comment there is an incorrect access of the array items in two ways. The array is one diminutional, not two diminutional. Then the return from the array is an `NSNumber` and that must be unboxed, that is converted from an `NSNumber` to a `float`.

The following is example code with the errors corrected:

```
NSArray * array = @[@0.240128f , @0.240128f , @0.953934f , @1.181351f, @1.382523f, @1.497086f, @1.437790f , @0.851196f];
float a0 = [array[0] floatValue];
NSLog(@"a0: %f", a0);
```

NSLog output:

> a0: 0.240128

Best bet: take the time to learn about `NSArray` access and Objective-C in general. There are many resources on the web both as manuals/documentation and tutorials.

Comment: thank u for your passion.
the array is working.
may you please take a look on my code and tell me what i am doing false ?
 ` NSArray * array = @[@0.240128f , @0.240128f , @0.953934f , @1.181351f, @1.382523f, @1.497086f, @1.437790f , @0.851196f];
    float a0 = [array[0] floatValue];
  ...
     for( i = 0 ; i < SIZE ; i++ ) {
       data[i][0] = array[i];
       data[i][1] = 0.0; 
    }`

Comment: I added the above code to the question, you can edit your own question. If it is not correct please edit as necessary. Please delete the above comment.

Comment: my main problem it was bye calling some data from an file.txt ( its  in this Question: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748427/how-to-get-from-a-file-txt-the-array-that-i-need-in-x-code)
i couldn't solve it so now i am trying to save the data in an array and to use it directly.

Comment: may you please take a look (if you have time) on my new question ?
[FFTw library](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23962954/3553742)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to initialise array, but in a "generics" fashion. Objective-C does not support generics.

Here's how you should initialise an NSArray of NSNumbers:

```
NSArray * array = @[@0.240128f , @0.240128f , @0.953934f , @1.181351f, @1.382523f, @1.497086f, @1.437790f , @0.851196f];
```

Comment: thank you for ur fast answer .
i was doing it like this but i am getting this error beside it:
`   NSArray * array = @{@0.240128f , @0.240128f , @0.953934f , @1.181351f, @1.382523f, @1.497086f, @1.437790f , @0.851196f};
  Expected ; . `
pointing on the first comma between the first tow numbers.

Comment: and by calling this array i am getting this error too:
`Assigning to "double" from incompatible type "id"`

Comment: @Eimantas The syntax is incorrect, for arrays use "[" and "]", for dictionaries use "{" and "}". The corrected statement: `NSArray * array = @[@0.240128f , @0.240128f , @0.953934f , @1.181351f, @1.382523f, @1.497086f, @1.437790f , @0.851196f];
`

Comment: Fixed the syntax in the answer.

Comment: @Zaph 
but its still giving me the same error :
 'data[i][0] = array[i][0];    Assigning to double from incompatible type id '
the element of the array musst have the type double too.

Comment: What do you expect `array[i][0]` to do, it is not a two dimensional array. Additionally the number in the array is an `NSNumber` and must be unboxed. What you need is: `float a0 = [array[0] floatValue];`.

Comment: @zaph
you are right, the problem is in my "data[i][0]" , the array is from type double.
i am trying to mach this two arrays , data and array. by:
for( i = 0 ; i < SIZE ; i++ ) {
       data[i][0] = array[i][0];//[self.array objectsAtIndexes:i ]; // stick your samples in here
       data[i][1] = 0.0; // use this if your data is complex valued
    }