# How to compile the FFTW libraries with correct architecture?

Tags: xcode, fftw

I followed the script on [Compiling fftw-3.3.4.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23279575/3553742)

But I am getting all the libraries of architecture x86_64. Thats why I cannot lipo them. ( libfftw3f_armv7.a, libfftw3f_x86_64.a, libfftw3f_arm64.a, libfftw3f_i386.a)

So any idea how to update this script to get the correct architecture?

P.s., by config. :

```
./configure --host=arm-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin --enable-float --enable-neon
```

I am getting the error :

configure: error: Need a version of gcc with -mfpu=neon

So I just delete --enable-neon and it works. Is it a mistake?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to delete my Question. But then I saw that somebody has it as a favorite question so  maybe he has the same "stupid" mistake like me.

I was getting all the libraries of architecture x86_64 because I was making a stupid mistake. It tokes  all this time to find it. I was adding `sudo`
for every `make` and `configure`. So thats why this scrip was not working correctly .