# Why I use NSFileHandle read file line by line,the memory usage grows higher and higher?

Tags: ios, nsfilehandle

When I use DDFileReader from [How to read data from NSFileHandle line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707427/how-to-read-data-from-nsfilehandle-line-by-line/3711079#3711079) to read a large file (about 37M),the memory usage grows higher and higher.

```
DDFileReader * reader = [[DDFileReader alloc] initWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tb_sentence" ofType:@"sql"]];
 NSString * line = nil;
while ((line = [reader readLine])) 
{
  NSLog(@"read line: %@", line);
}
 [reader release];
```

Comment: Show some relevant code about how you use it.

Comment: Hi,@KudoCC,I have update My question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resoveed this bug.That is because I have enabled Zombie Objects.Closed it,