# Cannot find interface declaration for 'NSObject', superclass of 'DDFileReader'

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new to OSX development and am trying to build a file parser. I found a guide on how to parse line by line in another stackoverflow thread -[How to read data from NSFileHandle line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707427/how-to-read-data-from-nsfilehandle-line-by-line).  I am having some issue implementing it. I created a new DDFileReader.h file to define my FileReader object, however, I keep getting the error `Cannot find interface declaration  for 'NSObject', superclass of 'DDFileReader'`.

What does this error mean? Do I have to load/require some external library?

**DDFileReader.h**

```
@interface DDFileReader : NSObject {
    NSString * filePath;

    NSFileHandle * fileHandle;
    unsigned long long currentOffset;
    unsigned long long totalFileLength;

    NSString * lineDelimiter;
    NSUInteger chunkSize;
}
```

Comment: `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>`