# Parser for String with Custom Indicators in iOS?

Tags: ios, parsing

I have a string format (with custom indicators) to parse, following is the sample.

```
@Parent
%ParentAttribute1
%ParentAttribute2
@Child1
%ChildAttribute1
%ChildAttribute2
/Child1
.
.
.
/Parent
```

But there is no indicator for defining child array. It is more likely DataTable in .NET.

Since we do not have Data Table in iOS, I would like to parse and create CF Objects.

Comment: You may be interested with this, and adapt it since it seems to be similar to TXF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28260743/optimize-string-parsing

Comment: @Larme I checked the above link.The direction given there for parsing is good, but my formats could vary, so I am not sure whether it is more generic. And also nobody uploaded the final solution, so I need to test different implementations as mentioned in the link.In comments I read, after parsing, user wants to convert it into JSON obj.Is this conversion necessary to use Model Objects?If yes, then we'd have used JSON, what is the use of TXF parsing then?