# Accessing text file content and character count very slow in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, text-files

I am working with a text file in iOS. The file size keeps increasing and reaches to 10 MB of size.The problem is accessing the content is becoming very slow.Is there any other way that I can speed up the process.Also, I want the total character length/count  of the text files.Its running in the main thread.

```
NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path  usedEncoding:&encoding  error:NULL];
```

Comment: So something else is appending to this file and you are reading it periodically?

Comment: Yes. Its a log file.

Comment: And what is writing the log file?

Comment: Some activities and whatever process is going on in the app

Comment: So you are writing log message to a log file and you want to read these messages from within the same process?  I think you need to think about the design of your app a bit more.  That is terribly inefficient.

Comment: Hmm.I thought of the design and its working fine.But only the issue is its slow.Well currently I am trying something.if it works I will post in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is too many solution for your problem :

1- [Reading file with more than 1MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044334/objective-c-reading-a-file-line-by-line)

2- [Reading file with more than 1MB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707427/how-to-read-data-from-nsfilehandle-line-by-line#3711079)

Comment: Then close as a duplicate.

Comment: @Aslam any update ? u said u will post your final answer :D looking forward for it

Comment: @Omarj, I tried putting my answer but I am not able to answer,its blocking me.