# How do I read in one entry from a plist array

Tags: ios, swift3, nsarray, plist

I am currently reading in an array from a plist using this code

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "levelList", ofType: "plist")


if let path = filePath {
    devices = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as! [AnyObject]
}

let device1 = devices[0] as! [String: AnyObject]
let device2 = devices[1] as! [String: AnyObject]
```

If I know before I read from the file that I am only interested in device 1 is there a way to selectively only read in that part of the array?

Comment: You mean, only read in that part of the file?

Comment: Can you give more detail on what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to selectively read your plist file only the first `device1` value, you should read the file line by line by `NSFileHandle`. However, you have to decide your terminate point while reading line by line, e.g. when you read to the first `</device>` tag.

You could check this link out as your reference [How to read data from NSFileHandle line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707427/how-to-read-data-from-nsfilehandle-line-by-line#3711079)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    let dictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.pathForResource("levelList", ofType: "plist")!);
let array = dictionary?["arrayKey"] as! NSArray
print("dictionary=",  dictionary, "\narray =",  array)
```