# iPhone remove <![CDATA

Tags: iphone, string, cdata

I am reading a xml and finaly just need to remove the CDATA Infos in my results

For example: I get:

```
 "<![CDATA[iPhone 4-Rückgaberecht: Deutsche Telekom kulant]]>"
```

just need "iPhone 4-Rückgaberecht: Deutsche Telekom kulant"

thx
chris

**Edit to your answers:**
I am not using NSXMLParser (thats the reason I make my own parser)

Found some suggestions with:

```
- (NSString *)stringByDecodingXMLEntities;
but dont know how to implement. I always get
> YourController may not respond to '-stringByDecodingXMLEntities" <
```

Comment: I don't know anything about the iPhone, but the XML parser **should** remove the CDATA sections for you. Shame on him/her/it if he/she/it doesn't.

Comment: I'd seriously recommend using NSXMLParser. XML is much more complicated than most people think. Rolling your own parser is a recipe for bugs and incompatibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i solved it with that:

```
 NSMutableString* resultString;


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)s {
   resultString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    [resultString appendString:s];
}

- (NSString*)convertEntiesInString:(NSString*)s {
    if(s == nil) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR : Parameter string is nil");
    }
    NSString* xmlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<d>%@</d>", s];
    NSData *data = [xmlStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSXMLParser* xmlParse = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    [xmlParse setDelegate:self];
    [xmlParse parse];
    NSString* returnStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",resultString];
  return returnStr;
}
```

call:   myConvertedString = [self convertEntiesInString:myOriginalString];

Answer (score 1):

use

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock

method instead of

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

thats it

Answer (score 1):

you could try a regex

replace `<!\[CDATA\[(.*)\]\]>` with `$1`

Comment: let me know how to to in objc-C :)

Comment: sry, don't know anything about obj-c. Seems like google doesnt find anything either. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422138/regular-expressions-in-an-objective-c-cocoa-application look at the accepted answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the String in String format with the  you can remove it like so:

```
//Declare what you wish to remove
NSString * suffixTorRemove = @"<![CDATA[";
NSString * prefixToRemove = @"]]>";

//Now create a new string which uses your existing string and removes the declared occurrences above
NSString * newString = [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:suffixTorRemove withString:@""];
//Now the first part has changed, time to remove the second part
NSString * newString2 = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:prefixTorRemove withString:@""];
```

Quick and simple :-)