# Regex to retrieve string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex

I wish to match

```
&amp;v=
```

and before

```
">
```

is there a regex match i could use

Example:

```
<a accesskey="1" href="/watch?gl=GB&amp;client=mv-google&amp;hl=en-GB&amp;v=ubNF9QNEQLA">Test Your Awareness : Whodunnit?</a>
```

i only need the `ubNF9QNEQLA`

Thanks

Comment: You want to *split* or to *match*? Splitting suggests you want to break the string into pieces based on some delimiter, but you gave two. Or do you just want to get the content that's between those two tokens?

Comment: Since there is no built-in full regex engine in Objective C (for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422138/regular-expressions-in-an-objective-c-cocoa-application), could you kindly indicate which library/function you're using to do the match with?  The answers thus far have presumed PCREs, but I am guessing you're using the built-in POSIX regexes which are significantly less powerful.

Comment: RegexKitLite is what i am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/&amp;v=(.*)>/
```

This solved it

Answer (score 1):

```
/&amp;v=([^(">)]+)/
```

Comment: I have no idea why it does not work for you. It works for me, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /&v=(.*?)">/
```

The question mark tells the wild char matching to be lazy so it will stop at the first `">` rather than at the last one.

Comment: @user, can you post a sample string?

Comment: as you can see i changed it from &v= to &amp;v= seeing as the code function did not work the first time

Comment: @user and did you modify the regex accordingly?

Comment: Yes i believe so, also i posted an example at the top in an edit