# Why isn't NSRegularExpression included in foundtion.framework for Mac Apps, as it is for iOS?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Why isn't NSRegularExpression included in foundtion.framework for Mac osx, as it is for iOS?

Answer (score 5):

I'd be very surprised if NSRegularExpression didn't make an appearance in 10.7, but you have to bear in mind that it was new in iOS release 4, which is a fairly recent release.

As such, I suspect it'll become part of the standard Mac OS foundation once it's slightly more mature.

Answer (score 2):

NSRegularExpression is included in Foundation in the newly-released OSX 10.7 :)

Answer (score 1):

Until 10.7 arrives you can use [CocoaOniguruma](https://github.com/psychs/cocoaoniguruma/)

Answer (score 0):

I miss real regex, too. However there is a similar functionality:

[NSPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html)

and you may want to check out a [related Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422138/regular-expressions-in-an-objective-c-cocoa-application).