# Time Regex in Cocoa

Tags: regex, cocoa, time, nspredicate

I need some help to write a reg exp to find times in the following format 00:00 and 0:00 (up to  max value 23:59)

```
NSPredicate *timePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES ??"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [someArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:timePredicate];
```

Comment: The array looks like this.  "3465,11:55,13:01,2311,122,4:34",     "3466,15:10,1233,13:11,6:56",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp) regex, [the syntax used in NSPredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422138/regular-expressions-in-an-objective-c-cocoa-application)

```
\b(2[0-3]|[01]?\d):[0-5]\d\b
```

It looks for a word boundary `\b` followed by either 20-23, 00-19 or 0-9, then comes colon and finally 00-59 before another word boundary.

The word boundaries are important, since they prohibit matches of e.g. 123:456.