# Not able to parse xml in ios application

Tags: ios, xml, parsing

Can anybody help me how to parse this data. As I am new to parsing Please anyone help me.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Tricon Type="Login">
          <Result>Invalid_Email_Password</Result>
   </Tricon>
```

My code for Parser is

```
  #import "ResponseXmlParser.h"

  @implementation ResponseXmlParser
  @synthesize myParser;

 -(void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 {
        printf("\n This is in parserDidStartDocument");
        response = @"";
        type = @"";
 }
```

ParseXMLFileWithData Method

```
 -(void)parseXMLFileWithData:(NSData*)data
 {
        isRootNode = NO;
        isResponse=NO;

            myParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
        [myParser setDelegate:self];
        [myParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
        [myParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
        [myParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
        [myParser parse];
        [myParser release];
  }
```

didStartElement Method

```
  - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:       (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
   {
         printf("\n This is in didStartElement");
             if (qName)
            {
                    elementName = qName;
             }
             if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Tricon"])
         {
          printf("\n This is in didStartElement Tricon");
          if(responseObj != nil)
          {
             [responseObj release];
          }
          responseObj = [[Response alloc] init] ;
          isRootNode= YES;
          isResponse=NO;
          response=@"";
          type = @"";
          type=(NSString*)[attributeDict objectForKey:@"Type"];
     }
         if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Result"])
         {
         printf("\n This is in didStartElement Result");
         isResponse = YES;
         }
       }
```

didEndElement Method

```
       -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
       {  
         printf("\n This is in didEndElement Result");
         if (qName)
         {
         elementName = qName;
         }
         if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Result"])
         {
         printf("\n the element name is :%s",[elementName UTF8String]);
         printf("\n the element name is :%s",[response UTF8String]);

         [responseObj setResponse:response];
          printf("\n the element name is :%s",[responseObj.response UTF8String]);
          isResponse=NO;
         }
         if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Tricon"])
         {
            isRootNode = NO;
            responseObj.type = type;
            printf("\n The type is :%s\n",[responseObj.type UTF8String]);
         }
    }
```

foundCharacters method

```
       - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
       {    
        printf("\n This is in foundCharacters ");
        if(isRootNode == YES)
        {
         if(isResponse == YES  )
         {
        string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];
            string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@" "];
            string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"           " withString:@" "];
            string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"         " withString:@" "];
            string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"      " withString:@"\n\n\t"];
            string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<p>" withString:@""];
            string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</p>" withString:@"\n"];
          }
          if(isResponse == YES)
           {
           response = [response stringByAppendingString:string];
           }

           }
          }
```

parserDidEndDocument Method
             - (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
              {
            printf("\n This is in parserDidEndDocument ");

```
          }
```

Here i am returning object

```
        -(Response*)getMessageFromResponseParser
         {
       printf("\n the response value is :%s\n",[responseObj.response UTF8String]);
        return responseObj;
         }

        -(void)dealloc
       {
     [responseObj release];
     [super dealloc];
        }

   @end
```

Comment: You didn't tell that what is the problem you have with your code.

Comment: didStartElement method is not calling

Comment: issue solved the problem is in XML file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing a lot of extra work in your parser delegate.  You might want to start from a clean, concise example like this:

[Simple and concise desktop Cocoa NSXMLParser example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576593/simple-and-concise-desktop-cocoa-nsxmlparser-example)

and change what you need