# How to check if an UITextField has numeric, alphabetical or alphanumeric entries in iPad application?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, uitextfield

In my iPad application, I have an UITextField. User should only type numerical. If user types alphabets or alphanumeric text then there should be an alert message saying "Enter only numerical". What condition should I apply which would find the entered text is numeric, alphabet or alphanumeric?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks and regards

PC

Comment: Use a regular expression:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422138/regular-expressions-in-an-objective-c-cocoa-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string'
```

You can then reject certain characters inside of that method.

Alternatively, set the keyboard style to:
`.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypePhonePad;`

Comment: You beat me by a minute.  :)  Though, the keyboard style isn't as good an idea as the delegate because of paste...and possibly external keyboards.

Comment: @Adam Johnson: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have changed the keyboard type to numeric. But this keyboard has Alphabetic keyboard option. Can I somehow hide that button? So that user has no option to enter Alphabets..

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting up an alert, why not prevent the characters you don't want?

If you implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` you can use it to detect whether the result is acceptable and either allow or disallow the edit.

Comment: My client wants an alert. I also suggested them to use numeric keyboard, to which they agreed. But still they want alert.