# Regular expressions in Objective-C to search a string starting with #

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa, foundation

My code is below,but it doesn't work.

```
NSString *regex = @"^#";

NSPredicate *regextest = [NSPredicate
                          predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];

if ([regextest evaluateWithObject:secondHalfString] == YES) {
    NSLog(@"Match!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"No match!");
}
```

Anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matches` in a predicate works on the whole string, so to obtain what you are after, write the regex like this:

```
@"^#.*"
```

Answer (score 0):

note that

`The predicate format string syntax is different from the regular expression syntax.`

[on the *Predicate* documention](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html).

for regex on cocoa look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3554488/1495442).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a string that starts with a certain string you should use something like `@"SELF BEGINSWITH #"`, it is much faster than using regular expressions.