# Objective C preg_match equivalent

Tags: objective-c, regex

Is there a way in Objective C to extract a part of a Regex found string?  The PHP preg_match code would look like this:

```
 preg_match("/{"id":"([0-9]*)"}/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

The data looks like this:

```
'7D16CFCB-2472-4034-B7AB-0A126C01FFC4', '9833496A-2B33-BF50-A37D84E8FB42', STR_TO_DATE('2014-06-17 18:51:47  0000','%Y-%m-%d %T'), STR_TO_DATE('2014-06-19 02:05:57  0000','%Y-%m-%d %T'), 'GMT (GMT) offset 0',0,'09989E6A-74F5-40F7-F0BF:d3e72eo8','Native','Ktel 2663' )[{"id":"184"}]1 record added to events
```

The result I am looking for is "184"  I want to identify the data I am looking for by the characters around it (e.g. id:) but I want only a specific part of the result..  i.e. the number

Comment: Your PHP code is invalid, the quotes are not right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expressions in an Objective-C Cocoa application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/422138/regular-expressions-in-an-objective-c-cocoa-application)

Comment: The prior question (from 5 years ago) has outdated answers other than the one that says that Regex is available since IOS 4.  I am still looking for an answer about how to properly do that in Obj C today.